# event.preventdefault() is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, event-handling, preventdefault

I have the below code

```
$(document).on("click", ".create_new_sdf", function(e) {
    var protocol = $(".prtcl").val();
    var domain = $(".domain").val();
    if (domain == ""){
        alert("Domain should not be empty !");
        return
    }
    var breakout = false;
    var prdcn = $(".production").prop("checked");
    $(".newly_added_row").each(function(index){
        var wildcard = $(this).find('.worker_wildcard').val();
        if (wildcard == ""){
            alert("Worker wildcard should not be empty");
            breakout = true;
        }
    });
    if (breakout == true){
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/***/******/',
        data:{******}
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            debugger;
            window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function(){
        },
    });

});
```

Actually from the above code the `breakout` variable was true and jquery was coming to if loop but it was not stopping with `e.preventDefault();` and going to `success method` in the below ajax function which should not happen, so what's wrong here and why the `e.preventDefault()`; was not working ?

Comment: try using `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault()` does not break/return from your function call. If you want to finish your function execution, then call `return`.

```
if (breakout == true){
    return;
}
```